# SQL Server Varbinary fields - identify the type of file thats in there

Tags: sql, varbinary

I have a SQL table (azure) that has a varbinary max field.
The field contains something, however i am trying to identify what type of file it is (Word, PDF etc).

Is there any way of doing this in SQL?

Comment: Yes and no. File types can often be determined through their [signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures), but not always. Things like Office files become especially tricky with modern types, since they're all just zip files and a further look at the contents would be needed to determine what application they're intended for (and decompressing the contents isn't realistic to do from SQL). In general, if the type is not also recorded with the contents (as the extension, or a MIME type) it's not possible to 100% tell what's what.

Comment: Storing a file exclusively in a binary column without accompanying metadata such as the filename and / or its extension is somewhat of an oversight as there is no ratified/standard/consistent way to determin a file type from just the binary data.